# Quickblox iOS Video Chat

Tags: quickblox

How would I determine every single currently logged in user that is currently available to chat, and then connect 2 random people with video chat without either person ever selecting another user (done in the background while the user waits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Chat room http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Chat_in_room

Every use joins room.

Every user can see a list with online users in the room:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark QBChatDelegate

- (void)chatRoomDidChangeOnlineUsers:(NSArray *)onlineUsers room:(NSString *)roomName{
    NSLog(@"chatRoomDidChangeOnlineUsers %@, %@",roomName, onlineUsers);
}
```

Choose randomly user from array **onlineUsers** and call to him.

While videochat - leave room, so other users won't choose you and your opponent for videochat if you are now having it

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, so that takes care of 1/2 of it. Now I have a way to see every user that is signed into the application. However, I want it to be transparent to the user. They should not see who is online and should not be able to select a specific person to talk to. Instead, I want to have the users randomly connected with other available users that are not currently on a video chat with someone else. Is this possible with Quickblox?

Comment: Updated answer, please check

Comment: alright, that makes sense, and that takes care of initiating a call, but what about the receiving end answering without hitting a button. I want the connections to be at random and constant. Think of a service such as chatroulette. The users don't ever have to do anything to connect to another user except tell the program that they are ready to connect to others. They never have to make or accept an incoming call, it just happens. That is the sort of functionality I am trying to emulate.

Comment: you can develop auto-accept feature - just call 'acceptCall' method in delegate.
Don't need to show anything to user

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful! I will give it a shot. Any way you could do up an example with this functionality? I think it would be very useful to have to reference and learn from.

Comment: @IgorKhomenko - could you help me with this one which is somewhat similar to the above please?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764844/quickblox-ios-connecting-2-users-in-video-chat-without-initiating-a-call